# calling removeEventListener from within event listener?

Tags: javascript

I have some simple code, but currently it does not remove the listener after the first call. How can I achieve this? Or do I really need to add redundant if/else checks on a var set upon notice?

```
    document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
        alert("Please remember this is someone's art! Give credit where it is deserved!");
        document.removeEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
            console.log('User has been warned...');
        });
    }, false);
```

**Updated code** Still same message every right click

```
    document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function msg(e){
        alert("Please remember this is someone's art! Give credit where it is deserved!");
        e.removeEventListener("contextmenu", msg, false);
    }, false);
```

Comment: it needs to be `document.removeEventListener`, not `e.removeEventListener`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to pass the same function to remove as add.

the easy way to do that is to give the function a name and pass the name to removeEventListener():

```
 document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function me(e){
        alert("Please remember this is someone's art! Give credit where it is deserved!");
        document.removeEventListener("contextmenu", me, false);
    }, false);
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener for a good overview

obligatory fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w1kzLkoL/

tested in chrome, firefox, and IE10

Comment: i pasted the code into the webdev console, and i only got bothered the first right-click...

Comment: @WASasquatch I get the same results as dandavis

Comment: @jasonscript dandavis didn't click a second time. I am testing on firefox. Msg, every, click.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this example:

```js
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", (function() {
  var done = false;
  return function(e) {
    if (!done) {
      done = true;
      alert('Warning !');
    }
    console.log('done ...', done);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  };
})(), false);
```

```html
Open console... right click
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I was trying to stay away from variable conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to just configure the event listener with `{ once: true }`.

```js
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
  your code...
}, { once: true });
```